# Insertar filas en una tabla de PyQt6 para un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt6

Buen día,

Para trabajar con `dataframes` en `PyQt6` se necesita usar un `QAbstractItemModel`. He logrado mostrar el `dataframe` editarlo y que al terminar la ejecución de la app se muestre el `dataframe` con las ediciones correspondientes, pero al intentar insertar filas puedo ver que se insertan en la posición correcta pero al terminar la ejecución de la app el `dataframe` resultante no muestra los datos de las nuevas filas ni los índices correctos.

Utilizando el siguiente código:

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
from PyQt6 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets as qtw

class PandasModel(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent = qtc.QModelIndex()):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent = qtc.QModelIndex()):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role = qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
                value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
                return str(value)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            return True
        return False

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == qtc.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == qtc.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                return self._data.columns[section]
            if orientation == qtc.Qt.Orientation.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])

    def flags(self, index):
        return qtc.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable | qtc.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | qtc.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable
    
    def insertRows(self, position, rows, QModelIndex, parent):
        self.beginInsertRows(qtc.QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1)
        self._data.loc[position + 0.5] = pd.Series([''] * self.columnCount())
        self._data = self._data.sort_index().reset_index(drop = True)
        print(self._data)
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        return True

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = qtw.QTableView()

        self.model = PandasModel(df)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        
        buttons = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.pbAdd = qtw.QPushButton('Add')
        self.pbDelete = qtw.QPushButton('Delete')
        self.pbAdd.clicked.connect(self.pbAddClicked)
        self.pbDelete.clicked.connect(self.pbDeleteClicked)

        vBox = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        vBox.addWidget(self.table)
        buttons.addWidget(self.pbAdd)
        buttons.addWidget(self.pbDelete)
        vBox.addLayout(buttons)
        # complete main window
        self.widget = qtw.QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(vBox)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.show()
    
    def pbAddClicked(self):
        index = self.table.currentIndex()
        self.model.insertRows(index.row(), 1, index, None)
        print('Add')
    
    def pbDeleteClicked(self):
        print('Delete')


app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
window = MainWindow(df)
window.show()
app.exec()
print(df)
```

Se creará la siguiente ventana:

[image: App]

Si doy click en cualquier celda, presiono "Enter" y cierro la app, el código imprime el `dataframe` que refleja las ediciones hechas.

Si ejecuto nuevamente el programa, selecciono cualquier fila con el cursor y oprimo el botón "Add" se insertará una nueva fila, puedo dar click en la celda y editar su contenido, presiono "Enter" y cierro la app pero al imprimir el `dataframe` en la consola se puede ver que las filas que se insertaron siempre están al final y todas con `NaN`.

Estoy utilizando `layoutChanged.emit()` que por lo que entiendo es el responsable de decirle a la tabla que los datos han cambiado y que se apliquen los cambios. ¿Por qué al editar únicamente los datos existentes si se reflejan los cambios y al insertar filas no lo hace de forma correcta?

Ejemplo del problema:

1. Selecciono la fila 2
2. Presiono el botón "Add"
3. En la consola se muestra que se ha insertado una nueva fila

```
     A
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  NaN
4  3.0
```

4. Hago click en la nueva celda y escribo "Prueba"
5. Presiono la tecla "Enter"

La siguiente imagen muestra como se ve la applicación:

[image: App con prueba]

6. Cierro la app
7. En la consola se muestra el `dataframe` "resultante" al cerrar la app

```
       A
0.0  0.0
1.0  1.0
2.0  2.0
3.0  3.0
2.5  NaN
```

El índice 2.5 tiene `NaN` en lugar de "Prueba" y aparte no se está respetando la reinicialización de los índices que está en la línea 43 del código (Tercera línea adentro de la función `insertRows`)

```
self._data = self._data.sort_index().reset_index(drop = True)
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el `dataframe` resultante sea igual al mostrado en la tabla?

El comportamiento esperado sería el siguiente `dataframe` al cerrar la app:

```
    A
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  Prueba
4  3.0
```

Comment: Agregue la última línea en su código 
`print(window.model._data)` y míralo.

Comment: Si, pero lo que debería suceder es que `df` se actualice como cuando solo edito el daraframe sin agregar filas.

Comment: como seguramente no es una respuesta válida será un comentario, te estás olvidando cosas: 1) el dataframe tiene alcance global pero la clase no lo está afectando directamente deberías usar en el método insertrows: global df  y antes del return df = self._data  por ejemplo. 2)No podrás usar "Prueba" como está el código actualmente, solo flotantes 3)el self.show() de la clase MainWindow es redundante, se puede omitir tranquilamente. Hay otras cosas pero no vienen a la funcionalidad.

Comment: Gracias @tincopasan, fue un ejemplo rápido así que tiene algunos detalles como lo mencionas pero el problema principal es que `df` se actualiza correctamente cuando edito alguna celda, esto sucede en la función `setData`. El modelo `PandasModel` que es de tipo `qtc.QAbstractTableModel` sirve como interfaz para el `dataframe` a través de una tabla. Utilizar `global` como comentas haría que `df` obtenga los valores después de insertar pero no es la forma correcta. Si te fijas en `setData` no hay ninguna referencia a `df` y se actualizan las celdas.

Comment: @tincopasan, no entiendo por qué dices que no se puede utilizar "Prueba", lo único que muestro en el ejemplo es que se le asigna un valor a la celda de la fila 3 y sí se puede hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta línea:

```
        self._data = self._data.sort_index().reset_index(drop = True)
```

está creando un nuevo dataframe, puede que sea una deep copy o una shallow copy pero son objetos distintos. por lo tanto `self._data` ya no refiere al mismo dataframe que `df`

Por lo tanto, la última linea del programa debería ser:

```
print(window.model._data)
```

O bien tomar `df = window.model._data` y luego imprimir.

O bien, como sugiere [HeytalePazugato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/171630/heytalepazguato) reemplazar la linea:

```
        self._data = self._data.sort_index().reset_index(drop = True)
```

por:

```
        self._data.sort_index(inplace=True)
        self._data.reset_index(drop = True, inplace=True)
```

para poder usar `df` y no tener que recurrir al estado interno del objeto.

Comment: Perfecto, si era eso! Yo creo que el nuevo objeto pierde relación con el `dataframe` pero en lugar de utilizar `window.model._data` lo que hice fue utilizar los argumentos `inplace` tanto para `sort_index` como para `reset_index` y separarlo en dos líneas. Si pudieras agregar eso en tu respuesta entonces ya quedaría completa. El objetivo era no utilizar el modelo interno afuera por lo que `print(window.model._data)` no aplica para lo que quería hacer.

Comment: Agregué lo solicitado.

Comment: Perfecto, ya acepté la respuesta y asigné la recompensa. Saludos!